# Bind json data in angularjs checkbox dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to bind my array of json data to angularjs checkbox. I am newbiew to this technology so I couldn't figure out the exact way to solve my scenario. I have json data like below

```
{
"hits":{
"total":3695,
"hits":[
{
"_type":"School",
"_source":{
"message":[
"HIGH"
],
"Class":"A"
}
},
{
"_type":"School",
"_source":{
"message":[
"HIGH"
],
"Class":"B"
}
},
{
"_type":"School",
"_source":{
"message":[
"HIGH"
],
"Class":"C"
}
}
]
}
}
```

I have to bind the "Class" value in the angularjs checkbox.

The angularjs code which I have wrote is ,

```
$scope.listofschoolname = response;
<label ng-repeat="ModelName in listofschoolname ">
                      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ModelName.checked"  size="10" /> {{ModelName.hits.hits[0]._source.Class}} 
                  </label>
```

I can get a single checkbox with value "A". Like that I would like to bind all the value in Class to checkbox.

**Note**: The json response which I am getting is dynamic in nature sometimes it have 10 class value(A,B,C,D,E,etc) sometimes it have only one class value(A) based on that my checkbox count and value should change.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You json is not properly formatted. Please create proper Json you want to play with.

Comment: @AnandG In that format only I am geeting the json response.

Comment: Then Json has some issues, its brackets are not getting closed properly. Check response json with Json validator

Comment: @AnandG Now I modified the right response

Comment: @Mangoski nope. 

Error:Expecting closing ] at end[Code 22, Structure 70]
Error:Expecting closing } at end[Code 22, Structure 70]
Error:Expecting closing } at end[Code 22, Structure 70]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you need to iterate over `listofschoolname.hits.hits`

```
$scope.listofschoolname = response;

<label ng-repeat="ModelName in listofschoolname.hits.hits ">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ModelName.checked" size="10"/> {{ModelName._source.Class}} 
</label>
```

Comment: I ahve tried the way you suggested but I didn't get the output.

Comment: I didnt get the checkbox. My page was empty

Comment: I got only one warning in my console. "Unmatched end tag".

Comment: There is a fault in my json data only. The tags are not in proper format. I just tried with simple jsonn data it working nicely. Thank you